# AngularJS changes in controller are not reflected in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have controller that has a prototype instance attached to $scope that has some initial values when user opens the page. If the user click on the tab, a service is called which pulls data from external service, extends the prototype and replace the instance in the $scope of the same controller. The same controller is used for all children tabs.  However, changes in the $scope are not reflected in view, but only if user clicks on the tab again, he can see the changes that were previously provided.

*Controller code:*

```
$scope.analysis = $stateParams.analysis;
$scope.changeTab = function (tabName) {
    $scope.selectedTab = tabName;
    if (tabName === 'table' && typeof $scope.datatable === 'undefined') {
       AnalysisManager.initializeDataForTab($scope.analysis.id, tabName).then(function(data){
       $scope.analysis=data;
       $state.go('analyses-details.' + tabName);
```

*Service code:*

```
self.initializeDataForTab= function (analysisid, tabName) {
        if(tabName==='table'){
            return self.initializeAnalysisDataTable(analysisid);
        }
    };
self.initializeAnalysisDataTable=function(analysisid){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var instance=self.retrieveAnalysis(analysisid);
    var method='tms/job/'+analysisid+'/datatable';
    $site.get(method,{},{}).then(function(data){
        var datatable=new AnalysisDataTable();
        var tablerows=data.rows;
        datatable.rows=[];
        datatable.header=[];
        angular.forEach(tablerows, function(row){
            var newColumns=[];
            angular.forEach(row.columns, function(column){
                if(datatable.header.indexOf(column.name)===-1){
                    datatable.header.push(column.name);
                }
                newColumns.push({name:column.name,value:column.value});
            });
            datatable.rows.push({textid:row.textid, columns:newColumns});
        });
        instance.datatable=datatable;
    deferred.resolve(instance);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

States:

```
  .state('analyses-details', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/analyses',
    params: {
       analysis: null
   },
   templateUrl: 'views/analyses/analyses.details.html',
   controller: 'AnalysisDetailsController'
   })
  .state('analyses-details.table', {
      url: '/table',
      parent: 'analyses-details',
      templateUrl: 'views/analyses/analyses.details.table.html'
   })
```

I've found several similar posts where $scope.$apply() or $timeout have been proposed as solution, but it didn't work for me.

**Edit:**

I've solved the problem in that way I changed navigation to the other tab, so I'm sending data as parameter so it's initialized again in controller.

```
$state.go('analyses-details.'+tabName,{
      analysis: $scope.analysis
});
```

Comment: Normally doesn't make sense to update a controller scope and then change state. Seems like something wrong in the flow process

Comment: @charlietfl I am using same controller for all tabs on the page. I updated my question to include how these states look. Since I have several tabs on the page, and only one scope variable that is shared between tabs, I thought it would be fine to have only one controller and update this variable when user opens new tab.

Comment: please include the plunker...